# How to make images are send inline while any other file is send as an attachment?

Tags: php, header

I have a simple question. I was looking for function to download file. I have found one but I have small problem.

First, this is some codes of function:

```
header ('Content-type: ' . mime_content_type($file));
header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header ('Expires: '.gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", mktime(date("H")+2, date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"))).' GMT');
header ('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header ('Cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header ('Pragma: private');
```

To test function I am using this:

```
$file = 'path/file.rar';
dowload_file($file);
```

It’s working fine and file is getting downloaded. But if I use the function for image, for example:

```
$file = 'path/image.jpg';
download_file($file);
```

Then the image is also getting downloaded. But I want it to be viewed and not downloaded.

If I delete this line:

```
header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
```

the image is showed immediately but the rar and zip files is stopped being downloaded.

So how to make images being displayed without downloading but any other file being downloaded? I am testing on localhost, may be this is the problem?

Comment: `it should be viewed`  oh, really? what else you expect from the function called "**download** file"?

Comment: @Null there is absolutely nothing interesting in it.

Comment: @Col It surprises me that you are still commenting on it

Comment: @Null as a matter of fact, I am commenting on your comment, not on the question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `Content-Disposition` header set to `attachment`, it will force a download regardless of file type.

If you want your images to be handled differently, you'll have to include a conditional on the `Content-Disposition` header, like:

```
if (!preg_match('@\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$@', basename($file)) {
    // this is *not* an image, do C-D: attachment header
    header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
} // otherwise do nothing
```

Comment: NullUserException <- thank you very much i was thinking about that .. it's good idea

Comment: Col. Shrapnel <- I advise you to a mental hospital

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a conditional statement on the files that can be viewed in browser and that should be downloaded. For images and xml files you can provide condition not to use content dispostion as attachment. For others include it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try switching based on file types.  If you take the extension of the file:

```
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Then you can whitelist your images as so:

```
if($ext != 'gif' && $ext != 'jpg' && $ext != 'png' && $ext != 'jpeg')
{
    header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
}
```

Or, alternatively whitelist your downloads:

```
if($ext == 'rar')
{
    header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
}
```

Comment: i have already used this code but i was looking for a profissional way .. but in finally i used it ! there is no another way! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> I am testing on localhost, may be this is the problem?

Nope. Not localhost but logic is your problem.

If you want to display an image, you heed a function that *displays an image*, not downloads a file. That's different tasks.

In fact, to display an image the only header you have to send is proper content-type one.

Comment: You do not understand! i am using htaccess to rewrite files from server to another one! and download job based on php files that's check if file exists on the second server.. so ,, without this function my site will die!